# What to use in DB2 for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: database, db2

I am converting some of my MySQL statements to DB2 database, but I faced a problem on the following query

```
CREATE TABLE RFX_EVENT_MAPPING (
  EVENT_TYPE varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  EVENT_DESC varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  EVENT_CLASS varchar(50) default NULL,
  OWNER varchar(6) default NULL,
  LAST_UPDATE_TIME timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  LAST_UPDATE_USER varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

As you can see there is

```
LAST_UPDATE_TIME timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Which is not working so how can I achieve the same functionality with db2?

Comment: sorry i just forgot to keep my caps lock off

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In DB2 9.7 for Linux, UNIX, Windows, IBM added the concept of a *row change timestamp*.

```
create table rcttest (
   c1 int,
   c2 char(10),
   insert_ts timestamp not null with default current timestamp,
   change_ts timestamp not null generated always for each row 
                                on update as row change timestamp
);
```

Comment: can u please give me the statement i couldn't understand what you are saying