# Create trigger after insert for current timestamp update

Tags: sql, db2, database-trigger

I am trying to create an archive in the following way. Created a replica of the table I want to archive from and added a column named DATA_PERIOD. My idea is to create a trigger that after this table is inserted with data from the original table, the DATA_PERIOD is updated with the current_timestamp. Here is the code I worte.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ORDERS_SUMMARY_ARCHIVE
AFTER INSERT ON GDTS.ORDERS_SUMMARY_A
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (DATA_PERIOD IS NULL)
UPDATE GDTS.ORDERS_SUMMARY_A SET DATA_PERIOD = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So when the table is populated, the timestamp is inserted.

Not sure if there is a  better way to do this. I've found that statement in a knowledge book and tried to adapt it to my needs, but without success.

> "DATA_PERIOD" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.68.61

Do I need some kind of reference to the table in the condition?

Thanks

Comment: Why a trigger?  You can declare columns to have [`DEFAULT` values](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_defaultvalues.html), including for date/time columns, which will insert the current time.

Comment: yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118614/what-to-use-in-db2-for-current-timestamp

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `before` insert trigger.  If I have the DB2 syntax right:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ORDERS_SUMMARY_ARCHIVE BEFORE INSERT ON GDTS.ORDERS_SUMMARY_A
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (DATA_PERIOD IS NULL)
    SET DATA_PERIOD = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. My assumption is that the AFTER INSERT would be -I insert data in this ORDERS_SUMMARY_ARCHIVE table and THEN the trigger is executed- Wouldn't before perform the trigger (update the rows with the timestamp and then insert the data)? I'll take a look at the BEFORE and let you know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use before insert trigger as suggested by Gordon Linoff. Reference variable for new record should be defined in trigger header section.

`CREATE TRIGGER ORDERS_SUMMARY_ARCHIVE 
BEFORE INSERT ON GDTS.ORDERS_SUMMARY_A
REFERENCING NEW AS N 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (N.DATA_PERIOD IS NULL)
BEGIN ATOMIC
 SET N.DATA_PERIOD = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. I've read something about the reference but didn't know how it works. Will check it. Thanks!

Comment: I was getting error with the SET part. I removed the BEGIN statement and worked. Thanks!